# how to load the file in just one of the columns of wx.Listctrl list

Tags: list, python-2.7, wxpython

I have problem with loading the file on one of the list that i had created using wx.Listctrl, i could open the file from a directory, but it is neither loading the file nor gives any error, and the PanelTwo.On.Open() is called from another panel.
It works fine until opening of the file, but could see no output thereafter.

I do not know what i'm doing wrong as i'm using wxpython only for a couple of months time, and could neither find any solution online.
please kindly help.

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self,size=(700,650),    
        style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_HRULES|wx.LC_VRULES)
        list1 = self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Command", width=300)
        list2 = self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Response", width=300)
        list3 = self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Status", width=50)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()
    
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def On_Open(self):
        self.dirname=""  #set directory name to blank
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file to open", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            with (open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')) as f:
                list1 = f.readlines()
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()
```

Comment: This looks reasonable to me.  Without more information it's hard to know what's wrong.  Exactly which line does if fail on?  And when you print out the input to this line, is it reasonable?

Comment: Hi Tom10, I fixed it, I had to insert the row to make it update that particular column when ON_Open is called, Thanks for responding.

    rows = f.readlines()                                                                                                                
    info = wx.ListItem()    
    for row in rows:
        info.SetText(row)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(info)

Comment: sorry i couldn't update the code format appropriately in the comments section.